# Non-uniform class occurances in input data for classification task - how to tackle it?

Tags: nlp, dataset, multiclass-classification

So, I gathered political articles for my thesis, now I want to be able to classify given text. Though the classes distribution is actually crazy.

- Class 1: 964 docs
- Class 2: 37,020
- Class 3: 640
- Class 4: 2,675
- Class 5: 793
- Class 6: 23,160
- Class 7: 2,665

Such a skewed data is obviously going to favor classes 2 and 6, though I thought about elevating the difference from last layer for classes with lower observations, is that worth a shot? Or it will actually create overfit for these classes? Unfortunately I can't scrap more data, the websites with articles doesn't have any more (at least now). Of course any data augmentation is not possible.

Comment: First thing you should try try is to classify the data as it is: if you're lucky, there are enough differences between the classes to avoid too much bias. Btw you probably meant "favor classes **2** and 6".

Comment: Yeah, exactly - thanks for the answer, I was about to do it as you say